# reflexion on param implementing interface not accepted as Class<T> param

Tags: java

In java, I try to pass a class param to a mapper using reflexion on the generic dto I receive as a param.

Despite all my tries, I can't seem to get it to work, even though I think my reasoning is correct and shouldn't raise incompatible types error in java.

Here is a snippet with a minimal reproducible example : https://code.sololearn.com/cTysx65IHL2Q/#java

I have an interface :

```java
interface IDto18Now<TypeDtoParam> {
    TypeDtoParam getAttribute();
        
    void setAttribute(TypeDtoParam param);
}
```

and 2 methods where my param implements this interface :

```java
private <T> T someMapperMethod(String paramToParse, Class<T> valueType){
    // some code which definitively works, as it's a mapper
}
    
private <SpecificDto extends IDto18Now<?>> void callerMethod(SpecificDto paramDto) {
    // some logic to take the string, it's actually a param but it's not important here
    String unparsedString = "some json or whatever";
    paramDto.setAttribute(someMapperMethod(unparsedString, paramDto.getClass().getMethod("getAttribute").getReturnType()));
}
```

and as you can see on snippet, I have an error where my types aren't compatible on the line where I call the `setAttribute`, where the truth is, for me, that they are, as the type returned with reflexion is, per the interface contract, the same that the one expected as param in the `setAttribute` method.

Currently I got this to work by passing an additional class param, but given my models are quite big and tend to chain lots of child dtos, I'd rather avoid passing the class param, especially as it should be guessable from the type of the param passed.

Can anyone 1, explain why this reflexion doesn't work, 2, what would be the best alternative solution for "deducing" like here the class to avoid passing it as an adiitional param.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the [getMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getReturnType()) method has return type `Class<?>` which is not compatible with the `Class<T>` parameter of `someMapperMethod`.

I think the simplest way to fix this is to introduce a `<T>` parameter to `callerMethod` and then cast the `Class<?>` to `Class<T>`.

```java
    private <T> void callerMethod(IDto18Now<? super T> paramDto) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        // some logic to take the string, it's actually a param but it's not important here
        String unparsedString = "some json or whatever";
        paramDto.setAttribute(someMapperMethod(unparsedString, (Class<T>)paramDto.getClass().getMethod("getAttribute").getReturnType()));
    }
```

Note that I removed the `SpecificDto` type parameter and replaced it with a generic `<T>`  parameter.  I then cast the return of `getReturnType` to `Class<T>`.  This should be type compatible with any existing `callerMethod` call sites but there could be corner cases I'm not thinking of.

EDIT: Understanding the error message

The error you were getting is

```
./Playground/Playground.java:13: error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
        paramDto.setAttribute(someMapperMethod(unparsedString, paramDto.getClass().getMethod("getAttribute").getReturnType()));
                ^
    equality constraints: CAP#1
    lower bounds: CAP#2,Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>someMapperMethod(String,Class<T>)
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?
```

This is a pretty unhelpful error but it gives you some useful information.  First, it tells you that the `T` parameter on `someMapperMethod` is getting incompatible type requirements from different places.  `inference variable T has incompatible bounds`

Next, it tells you what the incompatible types (really bounds) are:

```
    equality constraints: CAP#1
    lower bounds: CAP#2,Object
```

So `T` must be equal to `CAP#1` and a super type of `CAP#2`. But where are these constraints coming from?  The `T` variable is in the return type and the `Class<T>` parameter, so these are the two directions that may be incompatible.

The return type is the input type to `setAttribute` so that will impose bounds, and the input to the `Class<T>` parameter is from `getReturnType` so that is where the other bound comes from.

Finally, the error says

```
CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?
```

Because we know, from earlier in the error, that `T` has an equality constraint on `CAP#1` this tells us that the problem is that the compiler cannot prove that `CAP#1` is a super type of `CAP#2`.  Because both types involved are wildcards this makes sense.  Those types can be anything, so it's impossible to prove any relationship between them.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the advice and solution which indeed work, but why does the compiler not accepts this ? For me, the type must be coherent, as can be guessed from the interface, as the first type must be the TypeDtoParam awaited by setAttribute, and the second type param (given by the class) is found using reflexion on the same object than the one whose method setAttibute was called, to also get a TypeDtoParam.

Comment: Because the reflection API takes a string as the method name so it does not know you're pulling the return type of that specific method.  You could be calling `getMethod("toString")` as far as the compiler knows.  This is why `getMethod` returns `Class<?>` instead of `Class<T>`, there's no way for it to infer what `T` is.

Comment: To clarify a bit, you could define a `Method<R>` class which is parameterized over the return type and have `getReturnType` return `Class<R>`.  But this would require `getMethod` to be able determine what the return type of the method is, statically at compile time, which it cannot.